# How to add target blank in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is one problem to add `target="_blank"` attr in a link section in jQuery, please check below code:-

```
$('.ban-img4').click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that the link to open in new tab:

```
$('.ban-img4').click(function(){
  var link = $(this).find("a");
  window.open(link.attr("href"));
  return false;
});
```